# fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17

I want to use this file from https://github.com/adah1972/output_container/blob/master/output_container.h
this file can help directly cout STL container.

usage:

```
#include <map>
#include "output_container.h"
int main()
{
  map<int, char> mp{
    {1, '1'}, {2, '4'}, {3, '9'}};
  std::cout << mp << endl;// it will directly print result
}
```

but this file needs to compile with C++17, I want to modify the output_container.h to let it support C++11. But now, I encounter a compile problem.

*output_container1.h:53:51: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use ‘-ftemplate-depth=’ to increase the maximum)
53 |         -> decltype(::std::declvalstd::ostream&() << *ptr,*

I put my code here:

```
#ifndef OUTPUT_CONTAINER_H
#define OUTPUT_CONTAINER_H

#include <ostream>      // std::ostream
#include <type_traits>  // std::false_type/true_type/decay_t/is_same_v
#include <utility>      // std::declval/pair

// Type trait to detect std::pair
template <typename T>
struct is_pair : std::false_type {};
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_pair<std::pair<T, U>> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_pair_v = is_pair<T>::value;

// Type trait to detect whether an output function already exists
template <typename T>
struct has_output_function {
    template <class U>
    static auto output(U* ptr)
        -> decltype(::std::declval<std::ostream&>() << *ptr,
                    ::std::true_type());
    template <class U>
    static std::false_type output(...);
    static constexpr bool value =
        decltype(output<T>(nullptr))::value;
};
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool has_output_function_v =
    has_output_function<T>::value;
/* NB: Visual Studio 2017 (or below) may have problems with
 *     has_output_function_v<T>: you should then use
 *     has_output_function<T>::value instead, or upgrade to
 *     Visual Studio 2019. */

// Output function for std::pair
template <typename T, typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<T, U>& pr);

// Element output function for containers that define a key_type and
// have its value type as std::pair
template <typename T, typename Cont>
auto output_element(std::ostream& os, const T& element,
                    const Cont&, std::true_type)
    -> decltype(std::declval<typename Cont::key_type>(), os);
// Element output function for other containers
template <typename T, typename Cont>
auto output_element(std::ostream& os, const T& element,
                    const Cont&, ...)
    -> decltype(os);

//due to need modify decay_t
template< class T >
    using decay_tt = typename std::decay<T>::type;
template< class T, class U >
    inline constexpr bool is_same_vv = std::is_same<T, U>::value;


template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<!has_output_function<T>::value>::type>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& container)
    -> decltype(container.begin(), container.end(), os)
{
    //using std::decay_t;  
    //using std::is_same_v;

    using element_type = decay_tt<decltype(*container.begin())>;
    //using element_type = typename std::decay<T>::type<decltype(*container.begin())>;
    constexpr bool is_char_v = is_same_vv<element_type, char>;
    //constexpr bool is_char_v = typename std::is_same<element_type, char>::value;
    if constexpr (!is_char_v) {
        os << '{';
    }
    auto end = container.end();
    bool on_first_element = true;
    for (auto it = container.begin(); it != end; ++it) {
        if constexpr (is_char_v) {
            if (*it == '\0') {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if (!on_first_element) {
                os << ", ";
            } else {
                os << ' ';
                on_first_element = false;
            }
        }
        output_element(os, *it, container, is_pair<element_type>());
    }
    if constexpr (!is_char_v) {
        if (!on_first_element) {  // Not empty
            os << ' ';
        }
        os << '}';
    }
    return os;
}

template <typename T, typename Cont>
auto output_element(std::ostream& os, const T& element,
                    const Cont&, std::true_type)
    -> decltype(std::declval<typename Cont::key_type>(), os)
{
    os << element.first << " => " << element.second;
    return os;
}

template <typename T, typename Cont>
auto output_element(std::ostream& os, const T& element,
                    const Cont&, ...)
    -> decltype(os)
{
    os << element;
    return os;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<T, U>& pr)
{
    os << '(' << pr.first << ", " << pr.second << ')';
    return os;
}

#endif // OUTPUT_CONTAINER_H
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: There are several problems. You are misusing [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype), which takes one parameter (not an expression using the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That seems to be an issue in the linked library as well though. I don't see why they would do it however

Comment: @Lala5th I wonder if that's for SFINAE? The first, discarded expression to the comma operator would still need to be valid. But that causes recursive template instantiations between `has_output_function ` (in `output`'s `decltype`) and the `enable_if` for `operator<<` resulting in OP's error.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yeah probably. @haozheng It also seems that the circular dependency is caused on line 60 with the `enable_if<!has_output_function<T>::value>::type`. It seems as though it is a typo since the original uses `std::enable_if_t<...>` which is of course c++14 defined as `std::enable_if<...>::type`. In your code you used `has_output_function<T>::value` instead of `has_output_function<T>`. After fixing this it compiles. Also the code still has a lot of c++17 and c++14. Ignoring compiler warnings is bad practice. Also your code has many typos and will not compile (I mean `main`)

Comment: @Lala5th I re-write the code like this
template< class T >
    using decay_tt = typename std::decay<T>::type; 
template< class T, class U >
    inline constexpr bool is_same_vv = std::is_same<T, U>::value;
template<bool _Cond, typename _Tp = void>
    using enable_if_tt = typename std::enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
template <typename T,
          typename = enable_if_tt<!has_output_function_v<T>>>

if can let help remove decay_t, is_same_v,enable_if_t,which is not support on C++11.
but like your words, I still have some warning.

Comment: warning like this:
1. output_container2.h:74:1: warning: inline variables are only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’
   74 | inline constexpr bool has_output_function_v =
      | ^~~~~~
output_container2.h:74:23: warning: variable templates only available with ‘-std=c++14’ or ‘-std=gnu++14’
   74 | inline constexpr bool has_output_function_v =
2.
output_container2.h:132:12: warning: ‘if constexpr’ only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’
  132 |         if constexpr (is_char_v) {
I have put code here.
 https://github.com/peterzhenghao/print_container.h